# Require Root Paths in Browserify AND with NPM (getting rid of '../../../..' both places)

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, browserify

I've looked all over to try to find a solution to this problem, but so far no luck - even using the [awesome gist about better local require paths](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) and reading and re-reading the Browserify handbook's entry on [Avoiding ../../../../..](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#avoiding-), I can't seem to find a working solution for this problem.

I have a library, built with Browserify, that I'm trying to publish to npm, which you can [find for yourself](https://github.com/mmlc/Classy) if you want to test what I'm describing here. The catch is: **I want to publish it to NPM without using relative paths in my calls to `require()`, which is how it works when I'm using Browserify.**

See, using Browserify's `opts.paths` I'm able to change my `require()`s from stuff like

```
var Classy$Base = require('./base')
// and in another file
var Classy$Module = require('../../module')
```

to

```
var Classy$Base = require('classy/base')
// and in another file
var Classy$Module = require('classy/module')
```

Which is great! And it works great! And when I `gulp bundle` I get a working `classy.bundle.js` back and life is good.

So then I `npm link` and, in another project (which also uses Browserify), `npm link classy-js`, and nothing works. I get errors from inside of `require('classy-js')` saying things like "could not find module 'classy/base' from 'node_modules/classy-js/src...'" etc.

I want to be able to create a library where I can `require('classy-js')` and `require('classy-js/classy/module')` and get access to all the other useful submodules of the library, without sacrificing the non-relative paths inside of the library's own code.

**Is there a way I can do this?**

I have tried using [app-module-path](http://npmjs.com/package/app-module-path) but Browserify errors-out when using that, and I tried using [require-root](http://npmjs.com/package/require-root) with a similar result.

I have also tried symlinks, and adding an npm postInstall script for automatically generating symlinks, also to no avail.

It really seems like this shouldn't be so hard to do...

Comment: So you're `npm link`'ing to your source or to `classy.bundle.js`? How would you do `require('classy-js/classy/module')` if `classy-js` is a browserify bundle?

Comment: `link`ing to my source. I have my exports all set up, such that it *would* work in NPM if the `require()`s were resolving correctly. You can see the code using the link above, which goes [here](https://github.com/mmlc/Classy)

Comment: I'm confused though -- where does browserify come in? I thought you said you were publishing the browserified version of the library.

Comment: ahhh... Browserify just makes it easy for me to use non-relative paths. For the purpose of the question, I'm just trying to use it to illustrate that I want `require('classy/base')` (which is easy with the browserify build) to also work when using the library via NPM.

Comment: Oh ok. You should update your question -- as currently written it says you want to publish a browserify bundle to npm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's probably frowned upon, and I'm not sure I've seen a package on npm that does it, but I think this will work:

```js
// Name of module. I.e. same value as the `name` prop in `package.json`.
var Classy$Base = require('classy-js/base')
// and in another file
var Classy$Module = require('classy-js/module')
```

Re: this part:

> So then I `npm link` and, in another project (which also uses Browserify), `npm link classy-js`, and nothing works.

To make that work in conjunction with the first suggestion, also `npm link` `classy-js` *to itself* (almost). Say you have `/somedir/subdir/classy-js`. Make sure there's a `/somedir/subdir/node_modules`, then navigate to `/somedir/subdir` and `npm link classy-js`. Make sure you don't have `/somedir/subdir/classy-js/node_modules` and `npm link` from `/somedir/subdir/classy-js` or you'll have a circular reference that'll screw up module resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that I have solved this problem, although the answer is really dumb. Although [JMM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913650/require-root-paths-in-browserify-and-with-npm-getting-rid-of-both#answer-32914700) might have worked, I didn't take that route.

Since both projects are using Browserify, I can require classy into the second project just by doing `require('classy-js')`, and it knows to look in node_modules and find it. However, since Browserify isn't using the `opts.paths` that it does when I build the Classy bundle, it doesn't know how to resolve paths like `require('classy/base')`. With just this, we'll get a bunch of errors.

The solution is an `npm postinstall` script that creates an empty node_modules folder (Classy has no dependencies, only devDependencies) and symlinks `node_modules/classy` to `src/classy` and `node_modules/selfish` (another top-level module in src/) to `src/selfish`. This way we don't mess with the `opts.paths` of a separate project and our better `require()`s will work in node, too.

The postinstall looks like this:

```
// package.json
...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test",
    "postinstall": "mkdir node_modules && node create-symlinks.js"
  },
...
```

and `create-symlinks.js` looks like

```
// create-symlinks.js
var fs = require('fs')

var c  = '../src/classy'
  , s  = '../src/selfish'
  , cd = 'node_modules/classy'
  , sd = 'node_modules/selfish'
  , e  = undefined

e = fs.existsSync(cd);
if (!e) {
  console.log('link', cd, 'to', c)
  fs.symlinkSync(c, cd, 'dir')
}

e = fs.existsSync(sd)
if (!e) {
  console.log('link', sd, 'to', s)
  fs.symlinkSync(s, sd, 'dir')
}
```

It feels hack-y and wrong, but it works and it uses a similar convention to the symlink suggestion given in the "Better Local Requires" Gist. So there it is.

So far as getting access to submodules in Classy, it was easier (read: possible) to just expose any public API submodules (like Classy$Module) as a field of the top-level Classy object. So now instead of doing

```
var Classy$Module = require('classy-js/module')
```

or something like that, it's just

```
var Classy$Module = require('classy-js').Module
```

Which, though not entirely ideal, works and is "good enough."